# How to compile Siphon App for iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip, pjsip

I am download the Siphon App from the Google Project Code From: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout). But it's giving me an error for: **pjsua-lib/pjsua.h: No such file or directory**.

Also how can I add the darwin9 library into this project. I have follow the steps to get darwin9 library but last step is not compile properly.

Please give me suggestion the same.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251541/compiling-pjsip-for-ios-4-0

Comment: i have already follow these process ..

Comment: Try this one   https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles

Comment: try to make your app with pjsip instead siphon